# Upload rails app to firebase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firebase-hosting

I was wondering if there is a way to upload a rails app to firebase? If so can someone tell me how I can't seem to do it. I've tried altering the firebase.json file for my public path from "." to "app/views/pages" and try to deploy but a message keeps displaying that "can't find index.html in your public folder." If anyone can shed some light on this thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firebase hosting is a product to serve so-called static application, which consist only of files that the client interprets. Firebase's servers will not interpret any code that you upload. So Firebase hosting is not suited to host your Ruby-on-Rails application.

To quote [Firebase hosting's documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/):

> We deliver all your static content (html, js, images, etc)

**Update**: since early 2017 Firebase Hosting can be integrated with Google Cloud Functions. That means that it *is* now possible to run code in response to requests to files on Firebase Hosting, e.g. to generate hosted content on demand. At the moment this feature is limited to Node.js code. But that is dependent on Google Cloud Functions, so always check what languages that product supports to see what can be integrated into Firebase Hosting.